# JavaFX - Put a control (like a button) in a TableCell?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I'm trying to build custom content into a JavaFX table based on the object in the table cell. My feeling is that I can use the setCellFactory to do this, but I'm at a loss....

for instance...if I have an interface for my data:

```
public interface dbBase { ... }
```

then, each of my datatypes implement that interface

```
public class dbType1 implements dbBase { ... }
public class dbType2 implements dbBase { ... }
public class dbType3 implements dbBase { ... }
```

then, when setting up my table, I have...

```
dataColumn.setCellFactory(data -> {
   // what should I put here?
});
```

dataColumn is:

```
TableColumn<dbBase, object> dataColumn;
```

So, my question is:
How can I return a custom TableViewCell based on the type of the object in the column?

Comment: Are there *only* two databases? My first thought is that you can make two tables and showing or hiding them according by your condition. Of course, this is not a very elegant solution, but...

Comment: a) Only classes can implement interfaces. The `extends` keyword needs to be used for an interface to inherit another interface... b) You could make your `cellFactory` return different cells but this makes little sense since the parameter of the callback is `TableColumn` and you have no information about the item that may later be put into the cell. Furthermore the item type could change. You need to implement a cell type that changes it's look based on the item type passed to it...

Comment: Have a look at `SpreadsheetView` from [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/). It may be better suited to your situation.

Comment: zlakad, my data will have several different classes (two was just the example), and they will all be in the same list.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anyway to determine the type of the class at the time of the setCellFactory call, so I decided to subclass TreeTableCell instead. That way I could change up the GUI anytime an item was updated.

So, my setCellValueFactor and setCellFactory call now looks like this:

```
        dataColumn.setCellValueFactory(p -> 
             new SimpleObjectProperty<object>(p.getValue().getValue()));

        dataColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new CustomTreeTableCell());
```

and CustomTreeTableCell() looks like this:

```
    public class CANESTreeTableCell extends TreeTableCell<dbBase, object> {

    private final Button button;
    private final TextField textField;
    private final CheckBox checkBox;

    private ObservableValue<object> observable;

    public CustomTreeTableCell() {
        this.button = new Button();
        this.textField = new TextField();
        this.checkBox = new CheckBox();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {

            final TreeTableColumn<dbBase, object> column = getTableColumn();
            observable = column==null ? null : 
                column.getCellObservableValue(getIndex());

            if(item instanceof dbType1) {
                if(observable != null) {
                    button.textProperty().bind(
                        observable.getValue().getNameProperty());
                } else if (item!=null) {
                    button.setText(item.getName());
                }
                setGraphic(button);
            } else if (item instanceof dbType2) {
                if(checkBox != null) {
                    checkBox.textProperty().bind(
                        observable.getValue().getNameProperty());
                } else if (item!=null) {
                    checkBox.setText(item.getName());
                }
                setGraphic(checkBox);
            } else if (item instanceof dbType3) {
                if(observable != null) {
                    textField.textProperty().bind(
                        observable.getValue().getNameProperty());
                } else if (item!=null) {
                    textField.setText(item.getName());
                }
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setGraphic(null);
            } 

        }
    }
}
```